# Joomla K2 - List extra field from all articles in a category

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I've many articles in a K2 category called "houses". Each article has an extra field called "address" and I need to show in a page this extra field for each article.

Something like this (a là Wordpress):

```
$houses = get_k2_articles_from_category('houses');
foreach ($houses as $house){
  echo $house->address;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you have to [override your k2 template](http://getk2.org/documentation/tutorials/77-k2-template-override-package-comparison)

and add `<?php echo $item->extraFields->YOUR_ALIAS_HERE->value; ?>`